# Sorting numbers in Access and .NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have an Access table which has a Number field and a Text field.

I can run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY intID ASC
//outputs 1,2,3,10
```

But when I try to run the **same query** through the .NET OleDB client, like this:

```
Private Sub GetData()    
   Using cnDB As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Path)
        cnDB.Open()
        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY intID ASC"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, cnDB)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read()
            lst.Items.Add(dr.Item("intID") & " - " & dr.Item("strName"))
        End While
        cnDB.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

I get items in the order 1,10,2,3.

What's going on here, and how can I have the data sort "naturally" (1,2,3,10) in both places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY CInt(intID) ASC
```

to **explicitly** tell Access to treat this as an integer and not a string.  Obviously, something in the OleDbClient is seeing this field as a string (text field) and sorting accordingly.

Comment: ...and the "something" is likely what @Reed Copsey pointed out.

Comment: You're correct, but the "something" was an incorrectly set value in the settings of the ListBox I was putting them in.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the problem is your connection string.  If you're connecting to an Access database and include `IMEX=1` in your connection string, the provider will treat all data as `string`.  As such, the ordering will order by the string value, giving you `1, 10, 2, 3`, as opposed to leaving the `intID` as an integer, and ordering it in numerical order.

Comment: Wow.  I'd never heard of the IMEX option in the connection string.  +1 just for knowing something like that in the first place.

Comment: @David: It's because the provider supports Excel, as well.  In order to support Excel, as it's not really a DB, it needs a way to handle "mixed type" columns.  The provider checks 10 rows of data (by default), and uses that, but IMEX forces it to treat everything as text to prevent errors.  I see a lot of people copying it around in their connection strings (in Access too) without knowing what it's for...

Comment: Thanks!  I googled it as soon as I saw it.  I love learning new stuff here!

Comment: Interesting indeed, upvote for you.  However, the connection string doesn't have IMEX=1.  I'll edit the original question to include the connection string I'm using.

Comment: @Riddari: What is the data type in Access, for Table.intID?  is it defined as a numerical type?

Comment: It's defined as a Number, so yes.

Comment: Sorry, but IMEX=1 *does not* treat all values as strings, it is only relevant when a column contains mixed data types, and is generally not relevant for MS Access, only for text, Excel etc where mixed column data is common. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Comment: @Remou: IMEX=1 forces the ImportMixedTypes to go into effect, which, depending on your registry settings, can actually have that effect.  It's not guaranteed, but it **can** occur (Set TypeGuessRows in the registry to 0 or missing...).

Comment: You say "will treat all data as string", this is only true with mixed data types and sufficient registry tampering. This is stated in the cited article, and I know from many years reading posts that it is far more common for people to complain of mixed types *not* being treated as strings than vice versa.

Comment: @Remou: "is generally... relevant... only for text, Excel etc" -- actually, it's only relevant for Excel. For text the situation is improved because you can use a schema.ini file.

Comment: "IMEX forces it to treat everything as text to prevent errors" -- converting to text is the default behaviour but changing the ImportMixedTypes registry value to 'Majority Type' will change that behaviour. Also, changing values to text can itself cause errors e.g. when a numeric value is unexpectedly changed to scientific format such as 7504521e+10.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting a lexical (alphabetic) order.  This will be correct if something in your database or query thinks that is a varchar/text column type instead of a numeric type.